# Can you map serde_json names to different struct values?

Tags: rust, serde, serde-json

In the serde_json library, is it possible to parse json and map one property name to a different property name in the Rust `struct`?

For example, parse this json:

```json
{
    "json_name": 3
}
```

into this struct:

```rust
StructName { struct_name: 3 }
```

Notice that "json_name" and "struct_name" are different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [field attribute](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html) to tell serde that you want to use a name other than what you called the field in Rust. This tells serde that the json field `data` should be written to the struct's `new_data` field:

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;
use serde_json;

static JSON: &'static str = r#"{ "data": 4 }"#;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Foo {
    data: u8,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Bar {
    #[serde(rename = "data")]
    new_data: u8,
}

fn main() {
    let foo: Foo = serde_json::from_str(JSON).unwrap();
    let bar: Bar = serde_json::from_str(JSON).unwrap();

    assert_eq!(foo.data, bar.new_data);
}
```

Note: you'll need the `derive` crate feature for serde (`serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }` in `Cargo.toml`), and make sure that the structs you're using with the JSON data have the appropriate derive macros.

Comment: I get `cannot find attribute serde in this scope
serde is in scope, but it is a crate, not an attribute`. Do you need to compile this with some kind of compiler flag?

Comment: @Test sorry, yes. I forgot that the playground has a bunch of features enabled for the crates it has built-in. you'll want `serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }` in your `Cargo.toml`

Comment: oh wait, my macro error was about `#[derive(Deserialize)]`, not about `#[serde(...)]`. maybe you forgot `use serde` or something?